# getting the result from one gui to another gui in matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I have two `GUI`'s, 1 main and the other the sub `GUI`. I want to have the result from the main gui to be displayed in the text box in the sub `GUI`.

I connected my main gui to the sub gui by adding this:

```
openfig subgui.fig
```

I know that this wont do, I'm new in matlab. To display the result in the main gui i have:

```
set(handles.edit1,'String',f);
```

`f` represents the result that i want to be displayed in the other gui.

Answer (score 4):

You need a global variable.

Let’s say that we have

- a main GUI named main.m (with an associated main.fig) with one editbox (main_edit) and one pushbutton
- a sub GUI named sub.m (with an associated sub.fig) with one editbox (sub_edit) that will get the value form the editbox in main

**In main.m**

*Step 1*. Inside the **editbox’s callback**, add the following:

```
global my_data;
my_data.main.main_edit = get(hObject, ‘String’);
```

*Step 2*. Inside the **pushbutton’s callback**, add the following just before it’s return:

```
global my_data;
sub;
delete(handles.main_figure);
```

**In sub.m**, inside the opening function, **sub_OpneningFcn**, add the following:

```
global my_data;
set(handles.sub_edit, ‘String’, my_data.main.main_edit);
```

Let me know if it works for you!

Also, there are some awesome videos that you can check released by MathWorks Engineers, here is one video that can help you: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8616-video--guide-advanced-techniques

Comment: I don have a push button, is it possible if i could just call the output from the main gui, and display it to the subgui or i should create a push button to direct me to the subgui?

Comment: I manage to open the sub gui using the main gui but the subgui did not manage to display the result from the main gui. Do u know why? there are no errors in the code..

Answer (score 1):

Reverie - the line of code

```
openfig subgui.fig
```

will just open the GUI/figure and NOT launch the GUI in a way that can it can be used.  While opening it will display the GUI with all of its controls, you will get errors (to the effect of `Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.`) as soon as you try to use it.  Instead, launch the GUI by name as

```
subgui
```

which will be sufficient to start the sub-gui in a working manner.

Now, in order to pass information from one GUI to the other, you can try the following.  Assuming that you are using GUIDE to create your main and sub GUIs (which seems valid since you have a figure for the GUI), open the property inspector for the figure of each GUI and set the `HandleVisibility` property to `on`.  At the same time, assign a `Tag` for each, perhaps `MainGui` for the main GUI, and `SubGui` for the sub GUI.

Now, you can use the `findobj` function to find the other GUI using its tag. Suppose then, that we launch the sub GUI from a pushbutton callback of the first GUI like

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

% launch the sub GUI 
% NOTE - you may want code here to check to see if the GUI is already open before
% launching it again
subgui;

% find the handle to the subgui
hSubGui = findobj('Tag','SubGui');

if ~isempty(hSubGui)

    % get the handles structure of the sub GUI
    hSubGuiHandles = guidata(hSubGui);

    % get the data from the main GUI to pass to the sub GUI
    value = get(handles.edit1,'String'); 

    % now update an equivalent edit text field in the other GUI
    set(hSubGuiHandles.edit1,'String',value);
end
```

In the above we use `findobj` to find the GUI we are interested in using its `Tag` property.  If we have found this GUI (and so `hSubGui` is non-empty) then we get its handles structure so that we can update its edit text field with the data in the main GUI.

Comment: I don have a push button, is it possible if i could just call the output from the main gui, and display it to the subgui or i should create a push button to direct me to the subgui?

Comment: The push button (in the above code) is just an example.  However you decide to launch your sub GUI is up to you.  (Though I don't understand what you mean by *call the output from the main gui*.)  How do you intend to call the sub-gui?